# Surjection Vs Surjective geometric morphism

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Is it true that a map between ${\bf T1}$ topological spaces $f:X \to Y$ is surjective iff the induced geometric morphism $f:Sh(Y) \to Sh(X)$ is a surjection (i.e. its inverse image part $f^*$ is faithful)?

In "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic" a proof is given, but the the "if" part leaves me a bit unsatisfied (and, btw, the "only if" part holds for any topological space). 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with their proof? It's very nice and simple.

Comment: Why would $f^{-1}(Y \setminus \{y\})=f^{-1}(Y)$ imply $Y=Y \setminus \{y \}$ by faithfulness of $f^*$?

Comment: The right definition of "surjective geometric morphism", in my mind, is the one that says $f^*$ is _conservative_. See Lemma 3 later in the same section.

Comment: Ok, in this case I agree with you.. But it sounds odd that the proof is some pages after that claim!

Comment: The geometric morphism should be $f:\mathrm{Sh}(X) \to \mathrm{Sh}(Y)$; this is surely what caused @uncookedfalcon 's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want $Sh(Y) \rightarrow Sh(X)$ to be an injection not a surjection, otherwise take $Y = pt$, we're saying all the sheaves on everything are constant!

Let's consider sheaves of abelian groups, just to make faithfulness easier to think about.

Well, if $X \rightarrow Y$ is not surjective, take a skyscraper on a point not in image, it should pull back to zero. (this is where you use $T_0$, btw, to conclude all the stalks away from the point are 0).

If $X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective, then since the stalk of $f^* \mathcal{F}$ at $x$ is the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $f(x)$, if $f^* \mathcal{F}$ is 0, all the stalks of $\mathcal{F}$ are 0 i.e. its zero.

Comment: mmm.. I assume you don't know the meaning of geometric morphism, in particular surjections between toposes.

Comment: yeah i definitely don't...should i remove this answer?

Comment: Do as you prefer :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is some elucidation on Mac Lane and Moerdijk's proof.

"Suppose a point $y \in Y$ is not in the image of $f$."
This makes $f^{-1}(Y - \{y\}) = f^{-1}(Y) = X$, since all points of $X$ are mapped into $Y - \{y\}$.

"Since $Y$ is assumed to be $T_1$, $y$ is a closed point, so $Y - \{y\}$ is open."
That's because all points are closed in $T_1$ spaces.

"Therefore $Y - \{y\} = Y$, since $f^{-1}$ is faithful."
As @Zhen_Lin mentioned in the comments, we actually need the extra information that $f^{-1}$ is *conservative* to reach this conclusion, or at least that $f^{-1}$ is injective on subobject lattices, so you were right to be skeptical. While this is proved in Lemma VII.4.3 of the book using subobject classifiers, it is much easier to observe that faithful functors reflect monomorphisms and epimorphisms, and so the fact that $f^*$ is faithful and that a morphism in a topos is an isomorphism if and only if it is monic and epic implies that $f^*$ is conservative (and hence so is its restriction $f^{-1}$).

The strategy for an arbitrary space is to consider the stalks across all points, showing that for $\alpha,\beta:E \to F$ in $\mathrm{Sh}(Y)$ with $f^*(\alpha) = f^*(\beta)$ we have $\alpha_y = \beta_y$ for all points $y$ and hence $\alpha = \beta$, because everything is determined by the values on stalks. As you and they point out, holds for any space.